# PowerShell and Google Calendar API - Calendar.Events.Delete 401 error

Tags: powershell, google-calendar-api

I am having some trouble deleting a Google Calendar Event using PowerShell. I have sorted the OAuth 2.0 side and I am able to create and patch events, no problem. However, even when using the same access token I am unable to delete an event and get a 401 error (access denied).

Here is my PowerShell function:

```
Function RemoveEvent($tokens,$CalID,$CalURL)
{

    $header=@{Authorization = "Bearer $($tokens.access_token)"}


    Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $header -Uri $CalURL/$CalID -Method Delete

}
```

$tokens.access_token works fine for creating and patching events, and its current (auto-updates in script if its older than 3600 seconds)

$CalURL/$CalID is taken from an XML.config and works fine when patching an event.

Do I need something else to delete an event?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I wasn't passing $Tokens to the function, so it was empty inside it.

Updated the script and it ran fine.